# What is my battery max current allowed for charge?

Tags: battery-charging

I have a 5000mAh battery and in the spec it says "1C" for max charging rate. Does it mean it will be 1A maximum, and so it will take 5 hours to fully charge the battery ?

Comment: 5 amperes is right, but it'll take longer than 5 hours since there's no free lunch.

Answer (score 4):

C stands for the capacity of the battery, ao if the capacity is e.g. 2000mAh, then 0.5C is 1A, 2C is 4A, etc. In your case the battery is 5000mAh, so 1C means 5A. Google [battery C rating](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=battery+C&oq=battery+C&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3092j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=battery+c+rating) for loads of info on the subject.